# Encode a column with integer in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have to encode the column in a big DataFrame in pyspark(spark 2.0). All the values are almost  unique(about 1000mln values).
The best choice could be StringIndexer, but at some reason it always fails and kills my spark session.
Can I somehow write a function like that:

```
id_dict() = dict()
def indexer(x):
    id_dict.setdefault(x, len(id_dict))
    return id_dict[x]
```

And map it to DataFrame with id_dict saving the items()? Will this dict will be synced on each executor?
I need all this for preprocessing tuples ('x', 3, 5) for spark.mllib ALS model.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StringIndexer` keeps all labels in memory, so if values are almost unique, it just won't scale.

You can take unique values, sort and add id, which is expensive, but more robust in this case:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df = spark.createDataFrame(["a", "b", "c", "a", "d"], "string").toDF("value")

indexer = (df.select("value").distinct()
  .orderBy("value")
  .withColumn("label", monotonically_increasing_id()))

df.join(indexer, ["value"]).show()
# +-----+-----------+
# |value|      label|
# +-----+-----------+
# |    d|25769803776|
# |    c|17179869184|
# |    b| 8589934592|
# |    a|          0|
# |    a|          0|
# +-----+-----------+
```

Note that labels are not consecutive and can differ from run to run or can change if `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` changes. If it is not acceptable you'll have to use `RDDs`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

indexer = (df.select("value").distinct()
    .rdd.map(itemgetter(0)).zipWithIndex()
    .toDF(["value", "label"]))

df.join(indexer, ["value"]).show()
# +-----+-----+
# |value|label|
# +-----+-----+
# |    d|    0|
# |    c|    1|
# |    b|    2|
# |    a|    3|
# |    a|    3|
# +-----+-----+
```

Comment: Why does it need to sort them after selecting  distinct ones?

Comment: Because `distinct` doesn't guarantee any specific order. So if data is recomputed, labels can be different, even in the same application. This could cause some rather unexpected problems in your application. Sorting ensures that result won't change, unless configuration (number of partitions changes).

Comment: Thank you the option with monotonically_increasing_id() works well. But  after join on column with site names(string type) the values change(for example - "murmanout.ru" becomes "u'\x047\x19\x17\u0410\u0422\u0448\x1f\u041c\u2014_'". How I can prevent such behavior?

Comment: Looks like calling some worker side Python code on the way (not related to this question).

Comment: An `orderBy("value")` after `.distinct()` for the `RDD` solution gave me the answer that I was looking for and is consistent with the first solution.